# Char and bytes in python

Tags: python, unicode, byte, cpython

In reading [this tutorial](https://dbader.org/blog/python-repr-vs-str) I came across the following difference between `__unicode__` and `__str__` method:

> Due to this difference, there’s yet another dunder method in the mix for controlling string conversion in Python 2: `__unicode__`. In Python 2, `__str__` returns bytes, whereas `__unicode__` returns characters.

How exactly is a "character" and "byte" be defined here? For example, in C a char is one byte, so wouldn't a char = a byte? Or, is this referring to (potentially) unicode characters, which could be multiple bytes? For example, if we took the following:

```
Ω (omega symbol)
03 A9 or u'\u03a9'
```

In python, would this be considered one character (`Ω`) and two bytes, or two characters(`03 A9`) and two bytes? Or maybe I am confusing the difference between `char` and `character` ?

Comment: Forget any tutorials which describe Python2. Python3 makes such things simpler, and Python2 is at end of live (it is supported only for less then 3 months): do not try to understand things that are very different now (and that are already obsolete)

Comment: I'd suggest you read this write-up. It is from 2003 (by Stackoverflow founder) , but approaches the exact doubts you have right now: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, `u'\u03a9'` is a string consisting of the *single* Unicode character `Ω` (U+03A9). The internal representation of that string is an implementation detail, so it doesn't make sense to ask about the bytes involved.

One source of ambiguity is a string like `'é'`, which could either be the *single* character U+00E9 or the two-character string U+0065 U+0301.

```
>>> len(u'\u00e9'); print(u'\u00e9')
1
é
>>> len(u'\u0065\u0301'); print(u'\u0065\u0301')
2
é
```

The two-byte sequence `'\xce\xa9'`, however, can be interpret as the UTF-8 encoding of U+03A9.

```
>>> u'\u03a9'.encode('utf-8')
'\xce\xa9'

>>> '\xce\xa9'.decode('utf-8')
u'\u03a9'
```

In Python 3, that would be (with UTF-8 being the default encoding scheme)

```
>>> '\u03a9'.encode()
b'\xce\xa9'
>>> b'\xce\xa9'.decode()
'Ω'
```

Other byte sequences can be decoded to U+03A9 as well:

```
>>> b'\xff\xfe\xa9\x03'.decode('utf16')
'Ω'
>>> b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00\xa9\x03\x00\x00'.decode('utf32')
'Ω'
```